# Find the center of the circle given a LocationCollection

Tags: c#, silverlight, math

I have a bunch of LocationCollection of latitudes and longitudes and I need to get the lat/lon of the center of the circle. How do I compute for the circle's center coordinates?

EDIT : The lat/lon in the LocationCollection makes up the circumference of the whole circle. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please define what you mean with "center of the circle". I guess you want to calculate a sort of barycentre, see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Comment: Do you have any additional information? The radius would be most helpful. The standard form of equation for a circle is (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2 where (h,k) is the center, r is the radius, and (x,y) is any point on the circle. 

If you don't have the radius or the diameter, then a brute-force approach might be to try to find the diameter by finding the greatest distance between two points in the collection. 

Of course, this only works if you have two opposite points in the collection. If you can't find the diameter with certainty, you at least know the diameter is > the value you found.

Comment: @James no radius nor any other parameters except a lat/lon for every degree of a circle.

Comment: @Bahamut: do you mean that your collection contains 360 positions equally spaced around the circumference of the circle ?

Answer (score 0):

Which circle are you referring to? Remember that latitude is one circle and longitude is another circle so I would imagine you would like the co-ordinates to the centre of a sphere. I could try to explain the solution to you but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900242/how-to-calculate-points-on-a-circle-on-the-globe-centred-on-gps-coordinates) is quite good enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 positions in your collection, and if the radius of the circle of positions isn't too great (less than 50km or so) then you won't go far wrong using the formula for computing a `circle from 3 points` (Google that) and pretending that the lat/long coordinates on the (approximately) spherical Earth are y/x coordinates on the Cartesian plane.

If you have more than 3 positions then you have too many for a circle -- the problem is not that you can't compute the circle from (say) 8 positions, but that you can compute `8-choose-3==56` circles and they are very unlikely to coincide.  In this case you could do some sort of averaging to figure out one circle to bind them all.

As the radius of the circle you are looking for gets larger (I'm being deliberately vague here) then the plane approximation to the surface of the Earth gets worse and approximating an elliptical geometry by plane geometry becomes increasingly inadequate.  On the surface of a sphere, for example, any 2 points define a circle (the great circle that goes through both points) unless they are antipodal in which case they define an infinity of circles.  Now you need to be a lot cleverer ...