# How do I figure out longitude and latitude coordinates to create a 1 mile radius around a user's location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps, coordinates

How do I figure out longitude and latitude coordinates to create a 1 mile radius around the user's location? I don't mind how many coordinates there it takes, but I'd like to create a circular radius around one location.

**For instance:**

If the user's location is =

```
Latitude: 44.947 Longitude: -93.098
```

How do I then figure out what *8* sets of longitude and latitude coordinates create a 1 mile radius around the above location.

(8 in the above example is italicized as I don't mind if it's less or more than 8)

**How do I do this?**

Code so far:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

### Does anyone have any ideas?

Although I am pleased people are trying to help, the answers given below, don't answer this question.

Comment: [This](http://nationalatlas.gov/articles/mapping/a_latlong.html#four) should get you started on some basic conversions. There might be a better way, but with some geometry you could find 8 points

Comment: So you want to create a geocoordinates on the 1-mile circle around the user? Why?

Comment: Yes, do you know how? For use with an api. This is a requirement, I'm trying to figure out how to determine these

Comment: This should get you started http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance But I still don't understand the use-case for this.

Comment: What's the ultimate objective here? Do you want to draw a circle on a map, or just know the lat/lng of these 8 points?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900242/how-to-calculate-points-on-a-circle-on-the-globe-centred-on-gps-coordinates) is merely the same question, you just need to port it

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I can't follow that explanation given there. Also it's not in Java or android.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that I'm not experienced in Android so if this doesn't apply ignore me.

With the web version, the easiest way to achieve what you're looking for is to use the drawing API to create a circle of the radius you're looking for (in this case a mile) centered on your users location. You can then use the built in methods to find the corner bounds points of this object (unfortunately rectangular) to give you the long/lats you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a circle on map then do this:

1) Get a refference to your map fragment :

```
GoogleMap = MyMap;
MyMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_id)).getMap();
```

2) Draw the circle:

```
MyMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).radius(0.00062).fillColor(0x88000000).strokeColor(0x44000000).strokeWidth(2));
```

1 meter = 0.000621371 miles

If you don't know how to use Google Maps API v2 then follow [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: Thank you for your insight. But I'm not utilizing these coordinates within Google-maps. Do you know how to attain the singular pairs of longitude and latitudes to create a radius circle around the user's location as explained above

Comment: Why do you want to draw a radius of 0.6 millimetres? It seems hardly worth it!

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how to do that.